# Find the pmf of a dice that tossed

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> A biased die is tossed twice. Let X be the number of dots faces up in one toss.
>   Below is the pmf of X:

```
X        1      2    3     4     5     6      otherwise
pX(x)    3/20   1/5  1/10  3/20  1/10  3/10   0
```

> Y be the sum of numbers of dots that face up in two tosses. Find the pmf of Y.

So I think that the pmf of Y should be:

```
Sum  Prob
2    1/36
3    2/36
4    3/36
...
12   1/36
otherwise 0
```

Am I right? But what is the point of telling me the pmf of X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The die is biased, your answer assumes that the die is unbiased.

Compute pmf of $Y$ by

$$P(Y=k) = \sum_{i=1}^6 P(X=i)P(X=k-i)$$

Comment: If A be the event of first toss is 4. Find the conditional pmf of Y given A.  PY(y|A) = (0.15*0.15)/0.15 when y=5, am I correct?

Comment: yes, you are correct.